# How to order by number of keywords found in sql/namedQuery

Tags: sql, grails, grails-orm, named-query

I created a query with a like and a or

```
select * from xxx where title like ('%bon%') or title like ('%test%')
```

I receive a result with : 
bonjour je test
bonjour 
test bonjour
test

And I would like ordered by number of word in title :
 bonjour je test
 test bonjour
 bonjour 
 test

I use Grails with namedQueries.

Is it possible to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this little trick to count the number of space characters and sort by that.

```
select * from xxx where title like ('%bon%') or title like ('%test%')
order by (LEN(title) - LEN(REPLACE(title, ' ', '')))
```

Comment: I believe, rather `order by (LEN(title) - LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(title, 'test', ''), 'bon', '')))` - this will sort by number of search words (OK, letters in search words). But it's ineffective, CPU-intensive and uses no index.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try Search Plugin in Grails to index the text